# Zend Framework Paginator not displaying more than one page of results

Tags: php, pagination, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use Zend Framework's 2 Paginator to split up results. However, I am running into a slight issue when navigating to the next page link. It is giving the error of page not found. I'm not sure exactly what is happening, so I've included my route, the paginator route and two screenshots to show what it is happening.

members/lists-groups route:

```
'lists-groups' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/lists-groups/[page/:page]',
     ),

     'defaults' => array(
         'controller' => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroups',
         'action' => 'index',
     )
),
```

paginator route:

```
'paginator' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
         'route' => '/members/lists-groups/[page/:page]',
         'constraints' => array(
              'page'     => '[0-9]*',
         ),
     ),

     'defaults' => array(
         'controller' => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroups',
         'action'     => 'index',
         'page'       => 1,
     ),
 ),
```

The method to fetch the results from the database:

```
public function browseAllGroups()
{
    $select = $this->select->from('groups');

    $result_set_prototype = new ResultSet();

    $result_set_prototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Groups());

    $paginator_adapter = new DbSelect($select, $this->gateway->getAdapter(), $result_set_prototype);

    $paginator = new Paginator($paginator_adapter);

    return $paginator;
}
```

the controller:

```
namespace Members\Controller;


use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


class ListsGroupsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    protected $groups_service;


    public function indexAction()
    {
        $paginator = $this->getGroupsService()->browseAllGroups();

        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber((int)$this->params()->fromQuery('page', 1));

        $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);

        return new ViewModel(array('paginator' => $paginator));
    }


    public function getGroupsService()
    {
        if (!$this->groups_service) {
            $this->groups_service = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Members\Model\GroupsModel');
        }

        return $this->groups_service;
    }
}
```

I think it's something to do with the routing but am not sure so I went ahead and included the model + controller. I can include the view if needed but I didn't think it was needed as it's just a foreach loop from the paginator object.

The two screenshots:
[image]

[image]

As you can see, the routes are the issue (I think) but I have no idea on what to do to fix it.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks

Update:

I changed the pagination route so it is as follows:

```
'paginator' => array(
     'type' => 'Segment',
     'options' => array(
         'route' => 'lists-groups/[page/:page]',
         'constraints' => array(
              'page'     => '[0-9]*',
         ),
     ),

     'defaults' => array(
         'controller' => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroups',
         'action'     => 'index',
         'page'       => 1,
     ),
),
```

but this just displays the members index page with the url `localhost/members/lists-groups/page/2` (included a screenshot).

Any help again would be really appreciated, from what I've read Zend Paginator is simple to get running so I don't understand what is going on..

[image]

Update 2

This is the pagination control I am using. It is called on list-groups.phtml

`<?php echo $this->paginationControl($this->paginator, 'sliding', 'paginator.phtml', array('route' => 'members/lists-groups')); ?>`

Here is the entire module.config.php file

```
 return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Members\Controller\Members'        => 'Members\Controller\MembersController',
            'Members\Controller\Account'        => 'Members\Controller\AccountController',
            'Members\Controller\Messages'       => 'Members\Controller\MessagesController',
            'Members\Controller\Profile'        => 'Members\Controller\ProfileController',
            'Members\Controller\Groups'         => 'Members\Controller\GroupsController',
            'Members\Controller\Events'         => 'Members\Controller\EventsController',
            'Members\Controller\Status'         => 'Members\Controller\StatusController',
            'Members\Controller\Friends'        => 'Members\Controller\FriendsController',
            'Members\Controller\ListsGroups'    => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroupsController',
        ),
    ),


    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'members' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/members',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Members\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Members',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action[/:id]]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'id'         => '[0-9]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'status' => array(
                        'type'    => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/status[/:action]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Status',
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'edit-profile' => array(
                        'type'     => 'Segment',
                        'options'  => array(
                            'route' => '/edit-profile[/:action]',
                             'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Profile',
                                'action'     => 'edit-profile',
                            ),
                        )
                    ),

                    'account' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/account[/:action]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Account',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'messages' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/messages[/:action]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Messages',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'profile' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/profile[/:action]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Profile',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'friends' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/friends[/:action]',
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Friends',
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'groups' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/groups[/:action][/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'id'       => '[0-9]+',
                            ), 

                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Groups',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'events' => array(
                        'type'     => 'Segment',
                        'options'  => array(
                            'route' => '/events[/:action][/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'id' => '[0-9]+',
                            ),

                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\Events',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),

                    'group-admin' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/group-admin[/:action][/:id]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'id' => '[0-9]+',
                            ),
                        ),

                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'Members\Controller\GroupAdmin',
                            'action'      => 'index',
                        ),
                    ),

                    'lists-groups' => array(
                        'type' => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route' => '/lists-groups[/page/:page]',

                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroups',
                                'action' => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),

            /*
            'paginator' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'lists-groups/[page/:page]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'page'     => '[0-9]*',
                    ),
                ),

                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroups',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    'page'       => 1,
                ),
            ), */
        ),
    ),

    'form_elements' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            AddPhotosForm::class     => AddPhotosFormFactory::class,
            RemovePhotosForm::class  => RemovePhotosFormFactory::class,
            EditPhotosForm::class    => EditPhotosFormFactory::class,
        ),
    ),

    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'Members' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),

        'template_map' => array(
            'paginator' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/paginator.phtml',
        )
      ),
   );
```

Comment: Does your members route name starts with slash as you mentioned in paginator config? I think it's route array's key, not target url.

Comment: what exactly do you mean? it's a child route of members route

Comment: `list-groups` is the route name (a child route of members, so it would be members/list-groups)

Comment: İts starts with backslash here:  {'route' => '/members/lists-groups/[page/:page]',}

Comment: if i take the backslash out, the page redirects to localhost/members/members/lists-groups/page/2

Comment: i tried changing the paginator route to `route' => 'lists-groups/[page/:page]',` but that just loads the member index page layout and content if I click on next

Comment: Child routes should not include the path prefix of their parents - I think that might be why you are getting confused. Also, why do you have a paginator route at all? You have an optional page param in the `members/lists-groups` route.

Comment: I was trying to split up the groups being displayed by only showing 5 on a page. I just was following the tutorial for this on zend framework's site..

Comment: I was using this as an example to go by: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/tutorial.pagination.html

Comment: it shows the first 5 results (out of 7) but when I click on the next link, it shows the member's index view and not the same view as the previous page, yet the url is localhost/members/lists-groups/page/2... I'm really confused. I took out the paginator route as I didn't need it as you said.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include how you are calling the pagination partial (i.e. your equivalent of this code: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/tutorials/tutorial.pagination.html#using-the-paginationcontrol-view-helper )

Comment: did so, its under the last screenshot

Comment: That looks okay. In that case the problem must be in you routes - can you post the whole route config somewhere (if it's not too big)?

Comment: i couldn't post it all but I took a screenshot (hope that helps) 

https://imgur.com/a/k8rVF

Comment: @TimFountain I edited my post to include the entire module.config.php so the whole routes could be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you figured out, you do not need the **paginator** route. The **lists-groups** definition should be enough.

My assumption is that the **lists-groups** is actually never matched, but another route is matched in both cases.

First of all, change your definition to:

```
'lists-groups' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/lists-groups[/page/:page]',  // <--include the /
        'defaults' => array(                      // <-- defaults inside options
             'controller' => 'Members\Controller\ListsGroups',
             'action' => 'index',
        )
     ),
     'priority' => 100, // <-- priority
),
```

Set the **priority** to your route.
Remove all other routes, test if it works and then add them one by one to find the one that there is a conflict with.

Update: The **page** param is part of the route, so to get it:

```
$this->params()->fromRoute('page');
```

Comment: that did work, it stayed on the same page but it didn't display the rest of the groups if I clicked on next.

Comment: i added my entire route file to my question, maybe that will help?

Comment: @user2101411 That solved, try to get the param from route: $this->params()->fromRoute('page');

Comment: i can't award the bounty points yet but will do so when it allows (12 hours)

Comment: No problem, I will just edit the answer to include the param from route suggestion.